# How to visualize PhysicsWorld / CollisionShape with debug renderer?

Tags: urhosharp, urho3d

My test scene for Urho3D/Urhosharp contains two boxes (see screenshot).
For both, the red and the green box I added a `RigidBody` and a `CollisionShape`.

[image]

The shape for the red box is a sphere and for the blue one a box. I've enabled debug visualisation by adding:

```
app.Engine.SubscribeToPostRenderUpdate(args => {
    app.Renderer.DrawDebugGeometry(false);
});
```

However, this does not render the collision shapes but only the wireframe of the objects (green lines).

Here's the code for the blue node:

```
var floorNode = app.RootNode.CreateChild("Floor");
    floorNode.Position = Vector3.Zero;
    floorNode.Scale = new Vector3(10, 1, 10);
    var floorComp = floorNode.CreateComponent<Box>();
    floorComp.SetMaterial(Material.FromColor(new Color(0, 0, 1, 0.5f)));

var rigidBody = floorNode.CreateComponent<RigidBody>();
    rigidBody.Mass = 0;
    var collNode = floorNode.CreateComponent<CollisionShape>();
    collNode.SetBox(Vector3.One, Vector3.Zero, Quaternion.Identity);
```

And for the red one:

```
var boxNode = app.RootNode.CreateChild("Box");
    boxNode.SetScale(2f);
    var boxComp = boxNode.CreateComponent<Box>();
    boxComp.Color = Color.Red;
    boxComp.SetMaterial(Material.FromColor(Color.Red));

var rigidBody = boxNode.CreateComponent<RigidBody>();
    rigidBody.Mass = 0f;
    var collNode = boxNode.CreateComponent<CollisionShape>();

    collNode.SetBox(Vector3.One, Vector3.Zero, Quaternion.Identity);
    collNode.SetSphere(3f, Vector3.Zero, Quaternion.Identity);
```

The collision works but I'd love to see the physics world because it makes it easier to experiment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And here's the solution: the default debug output of the Urho3D renderer does not include the physics components. It has to be added manually.

```
app.Engine.SubscribeToPostRenderUpdate(args => {
    // Default debug rendering.
    app.Renderer.DrawDebugGeometry(false);

    // Use debug renderer to output physics world debug.
    var debugRendererComp = app.Scene.GetComponent<DebugRenderer>();
    var physicsComp = app.Scene.GetComponent<PhysicsWorld>();
    if(physicsComp != null)
    {
        physicsComp.DrawDebugGeometry(debugRendererComp, false);
    }
});
```

For this to work the scene must of course have a debug renderer and a physics component:

```
app.Scene.GetOrCreateComponent<PhysicsWorld>();
app.Scene.GetOrCreateComponent<DebugRenderer>();
```

Then the result is as expected. In the image below the red box has got a spherical collision shape:

[image: Physics debug rendering]

The nice thing I noticed: since the collision shape is a child node of the actual node it will scale together with the node. This means if the box or sphere (or whatever) is created with a size of `Vector3.One` it will always match the actual node size.